# Get input value plugin octobercms backend

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

How to assign an input value to variable in plugins bacckend form.

`$termid = Input::get('term_id');` // this code doesn't work for me.

```
namespace Cng\Tennis\Models;
use Model;
use Flash;
use Db;
use Input;

class Lesson extends Model {

    public function getSdateOptions () {

            // $attributes = $this->getAttributes();
            // $termid = $attributes['term_id'];

            $termid = Input::get('term_id');

        if ($this->term_id == $termid ) {
            $term = Db::table('cng_tennis_term')->where('id', $termid )->first();
            return [  $term->start_date =>  $term->finish_date ]; 
        }
        else {
            return ['Select a date' => 'Select a date' ];
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
namespace Cng\Tennis\Models;
use Model;
use Flash;
use Db;
use Input;

class Lesson extends Model {

    public static function getSdateOptions ($term_id = null) {
        if(!$term_id){return false;}
            // $attributes = $this->getAttributes();
            // $termid = $attributes['term_id'];

        if ($this->term_id == $termid ) {
            $term = Db::table('cng_tennis_term')->where('id', $termid )->first();
            return [  $term->start_date =>  $term->finish_date ]; 
        }
        else {
            return ['Select a date' => 'Select a date' ];
            } 
        }
```

and in your **controller** or **components**

```
 $result = Lesson::getSdateOptions(Input::get('term_id'));
```

i hope help you